# DSGE and Demography

Tags: macroeconomics, demographics

Are there any known DSGE models with a demography component, i.e., that model the effects of aging population in output growth?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I've been thinking, this question might not make much sense since I think DSGE are usually used for fluctuations/medium-run, whereas demography seems to be more like a long-run issue... not sure though.

Comment: Just as a brain storm ; some epidemics that take place each year in some regions of the world ? So in this case, it would be interesting to see its effect on macroeconomic indicators.

Comment: @optimalcontrol Nice! I hadn't thought about that! ;)

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: Related (but probably too broad) : http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/economic-impacts-of-a-declining-population

Comment: see this question: http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/economic-impacts-of-a-declining-population?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not my field at all but with a quick search I found an [ECB working paper from 2010 "INTEREST RATE EFFECTS OF DEMOGRAPHIC CHANGES IN A NEW-KEYNESIAN LIFE-CYCLE FRAMEWORK", by Engin Kara and Leopold von Thadden](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecbwp1273.pdf?69ebca156c9ef673d45cdcb4e32a1f95).

The [dynare forum](http://www.dynare.org/phpBB3/) is more specialized on DSGE models, you will probably get better advice there. With a [quick search there](http://www.dynare.org/phpBB3/search.php?keywords=%2Bdemographic%20%20) you find several posts that already included something with demography.